# how can we take input from user in H:M:S format without am/pm in html

Tags: javascript, forms, input, time, user-input

I am stuck in a project where I need to create a form in which user can put session time in h:m:s format like **01:05:08** (I need to get input of same format without am/pm thing )

thanks
looking forward for your solutions

Comment: That is not how Stackoverflow works. If you share an (incomplete) implementation, people can help you improve. But we wont do your school assignments for you.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)? Some more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms).

Comment: yes i do follow the documentation and examples but in chrome every input of time show with am/pm and I want set time without am/pm

Answer (score 0):

Check input types, one of them is:

```
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" required>
```

Comment: i already used this but this input shows time with am/pm

Comment: It depends upon user's system clock if it's in 12 hour format it will show am/pm. if you just want to get time without am/pm then you can use substring to separate time and am/pm